# GPU Compatibility for Theano [NVidia GeForce 8800GT]

Tags: cuda, gpu, tensorflow, theano, theano-cuda

I am currently working on an ML project on my personal computer that has an AMD graphics card. I have an old NVidia 8800GT card that I could plug in for CUDA accelerated convolution, but I haven't found if it is compatible with Theano. Googling has surprisingly been unsuccessful.

I know the 8800GT supports CUDA and I've done some CUDA work with it in the past, but is compatible with Theano? (or TensorFlow?)

Best,
Joe

Comment: It's not clear that you'll get any benefit from 8800GT. I tried on similar price range GeForce 730 and it had about the same speed for matmul as my z420 workstation without acceleration

Comment: 8800GT is not supported by CUDA 7.0 or CUDA 7.5, and also not supported by cuDNN.

Comment: Do you have a link to a compatibility listing? I might head out and buy a compatible mid-line GPU then.

Comment: There is a list of cuda-compatible GPUs here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Answer (score 1):

Theano has no specific requirements for cards other than "it works with cuda".

If you want to use the cuDNN layers or other specilized things, then you might need a more recent card and the requirements for those is specified in the documentation for those libraries.